# percentage symbol gnumake meaning

Tags: gnu-make

```
%.o: %.c $(PROOT)/include/curl/curlbuild.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I would like to know the meaning of the percentage symbol in this situation, I am triing to compile curl 7.49.1. Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read: [Defining and Redefining Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html)